# Jquery: animate element randomly on click

Tags: jquery, animation

I wonder if I can animate elements on click randomly. I have this code:

```
$('.div').click(function(){
       if( $(this).hasClass('active')){
           var divAnim=$(this).animate({bottom:'+=600', left:'+=600'},1000);
           var rand=Math.floor(Math.random() * divAnim);
           rand;
       }
       return true;

  });
```

But the result is the same without the line "Math Random". Is it possible to achieve a random animation that changes the default values?

Comment: What part do you want to be random? Should the position be random (i.e. the `+=600`), or the time (`1000`), or both? Or something else?

Comment: I am more intersted in the positions

Comment: maybe if I set the random value right on those values?

Comment: Yes. That makes more sense.

Comment: You don't need that `var rand` at all. The `rand;` statement does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? (P.s typing on my phone)

```
 $('.div').click(function(){
   if( $(this).hasClass('active')){

 var randomHeight= Math.floor(Math.random() * $(window).height());


 var randomWidth= Math.floor(Math.random() * $(window).width());


       $(this).animate({bottom: randomHeight, left:     randomWidth},1000);

   }
   return true;

  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example snippet of jquery site. Note the CSS part. Your div container needs an absolute position so it knows where to start from.

```js
function makeNewPosition(){
    
    // Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
    var h = $('#block_wrapper').height() - 50;
    var w = $('#block_wrapper').width() - 50;
    
    var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
    var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);
    
    return [nh,nw];    
    
}
$( "#go" ).click(function() {

  var pos = makeNewPosition();
  $('#block').animate({ top: pos[0], left: pos[1] });
  
});
```

```css
#block_wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width:600px;
    height:400px;
    background:#f4f4f4;
  }
  #block {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #abc;
    left: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 5px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="go">&raquo; Run</button>
<div id="block_wrapper">
<div id="block">Hello!</div>
</div>
```

UPDATED SNIPPED ABOVE

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i'm having trouble on writting/trigering a random value for a particular value, like position (inside the animation statement)